# How do I import a private key from a hard copy?

Tags: gnupg, file-encryption

I started playing with encrypting some personal files, and I exported the private key as an .asc file, but also on hard copy (plain paper) and can't understand a thing about how it says to import it from there... It looks more like a recovery option using some of the bites printed... How does that even work? I'm on kleopatra on windows so I have no idea if I have to do it from cl or how that works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import it from paper you broadly speaking have two options:

1. Type it in. Sure, it takes a few hours, but it's doable.
2. Read it using [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition).

Typing it in will take a while. If you ally yourself with a hilighter, it's entirely doable, albeit boring.

If you decide to OCR it, your mileage may vary, depending on what font and font size you used, and how well preserved the hardcopy is.

Once you have typed it in or OCR'd it, simply import that keyfile into Kleopatra.

Comment: I actually have Abby FineReader for OCR and it works pretty well... But in what format would I save that file... Is it as simple as saving it as a .txt?

Comment: Plus, there is this other thing it's confusing me... With switching packet tags...?

  To recover a secret key without using the paperkey program, use the
# key fingerprint to match an existing public key packet with the
# corresponding secret data from the paper key. Next, append this secret
# data to the public key packet. Finally, switch the public key packet tag
# from 6 to 5 (14 to 7 for subkeys). This will recreate the original secret
# key or secret subkey packet.

Comment: @Unix: *...works pretty well...* It's likely that it needs to work perfectly with no mistakes. There is a checksum so you can use gnupg to test the result and know if the OCR got it right. I don't suppose FineReader has an option for base64 text?

Comment: @President James K. Polk No but at my last job it never failed on printed text... Only Handwritten...

Comment: @Unix: Go for it, it's probably true that Kleopatra will verify the checksum whenever it reads that file anyway.

Comment: Ok so apparently I do have to use the paperkay software... But it can't parse the public file since it's "armored" and the --dearmor command is not available... Any tips on that?

Comment: So you used some piece of software to print the key, you didn't merely print the ascii armored version of the key? If so read the manual for that piece of software.

Comment: Speaking from experience, I would not recommend relying on OCR to restore a private key from printed text. It really does need to be 100% accurate, and the best widely available OCR software I could find did not get anywhere close. I even wrote a custom OCR program specifically targeted at handling the scans I'm working with, and despite getting the recognition accuracy up to about 99% (maybe 99.5%, it's hard to be sure), it's still not good enough. Better to just type it out.